# Why is visual studio telling me I am running a different version of C# than what I am targeting in a WCF Service Project?

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a new WCF Service Project targeting framework 4.7.2 in Visual Studio, but when I try to code an interpolated string, i get an error that interpolated strings are not available in C#5, please use version 6 or higher. The only place I see any mention of versioning is in the web.config file, and I confirmed that it indeed is targetting 4.7.2. Does anyone know how to fix this, and why its happening?

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**TestMethod where error occurs**

```
    public string GetCurrentCount()
    {
        return $"Random stfuf";
    }
```

Comment: Wat about your `.csproj` file (the **project** file, search this in the file explorer)?

Comment: Right click on your project, select "properties" and tell us what is your framework

Comment: RIghtClick>Properties is not visible in the WCF Service Project

Comment: `4.7.2` is the *framework* version, not the language version.

Comment: @Amy 4.7.2 corresponds to C# version 8, does it not?

Comment: @cubesnyc No, they are completely unrelated.

Comment: @Amy ok. Do you know how to fix the issue?

Comment: @cubesnyc I'm not familiar with WCF projects, but this might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: @Amy the first two paragraphs of that page contradict what you are saying about how they are completely unrelated.

Comment: @cubesnyc It's not contradictory. When you target `netcoreapp3.0`, it will *default* to C# 8. You could use C# 5 if you wanted.  Targeting any release version of .Net Core will *by default* target C# 7.3. You could also use C# 5 with .Net 4.0.  They are unrelated.  Keep reading: `You can override the default behavior by specifying a language version.`